# Drawing to screen directly on top of all window

Tags: c#, java, c++, windows

I need a way to draw to the display screen directly in Windows. The things the program needs to draw are very simple shapes and some text.

I want to develop a program that works similarly to Xfire. Namely that it can draw on top of a full-screen application. So for example I want to create a program that runs in the background all the time, and displays system time in the lower right corner even when a full-screen application is running (Game, film, etc..). My program also has to react on events like pushing a button combination (for example ctrl+alt+1).

My program must not capture mouse events. So if it draws a circle and there is a button for a foreign application under it, the foreign application's button should recognize the click.

How is this possible in Windows?

I want to implement this program in one of the following languages: C++, C#, Java

I would be grateful for some APIs/tutorials that can help me implement this.

Comment: My rudimentary, personal XP (without ability to change things) time+date thing that does that looks pretty bad in fullscreen applications. Just saying.

Comment: You might want to draw it on top of DirectX
http://spazzarama.com/2011/03/14/c-screen-capture-and-overlays-for-direct3d-9-10-and-11-using-api-hooks/