# Is there a way to draw graphics on screen without a pictureBox and without any control?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, directx

In this method i need to give it a pictureBox:

```
private Boolean InitializeDirectX()
        {

            DispMode = Manager.Adapters[Manager.Adapters.Default.Adapter].CurrentDisplayMode;
            D3Dpp = new PresentParameters();
            D3Dpp.BackBufferFormat = DispMode.Format;
            D3Dpp.PresentFlag = PresentFlag.LockableBackBuffer;

            D3Dpp.SwapEffect = SwapEffect.Discard;
            D3Dpp.PresentationInterval = PresentInterval.One; //wait for vertical sync. Synchronizes the painting with
                                                              //monitor refresh rate for smoooth animation
            D3Dpp.Windowed = true; //the application has borders

            try
            {
                D3Ddev = new Device(Manager.Adapters.Default.Adapter, DeviceType.Hardware, pb1.Handle,
                                                                           CreateFlags.SoftwareVertexProcessing, D3Dpp);
                D3Ddev.RenderState.Lighting = false;
                D3Ddev.RenderState.CullMode = Cull.CounterClockwise;


                backTexture = TextureLoader.FromStream(D3Ddev, mymem);
                scannedCloudsTexture = new Texture(D3Ddev, 512, 512, 1, Usage.Dynamic, Format.A8R8G8B8, Pool.Default);

                //sprite is used to draw the texture
                D3Dsprite = new Sprite(D3Ddev);

                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

The line is:

```
D3Ddev = new Device(Manager.Adapters.Default.Adapter, DeviceType.Hardware, pb1.Handle,                                                                          CreateFlags.SoftwareVertexProcessing, D3Dpp);
```

pb1 should be pictureBox and i should put there the pictureBox Handle.
But instead a pictureBox maybe there is a way to use the screen it self ?

I saw something :

```
System.Windows.Forms.Screen.FromHandle
```

But not sure if this is what i need. And it also need to get intptr.

Comment: `Windows.Draw `

Comment: On the screen as opposed to onto a Form?

Comment: TaW right. you are right.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Drawing to screen directly on top of all window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15798119/drawing-to-screen-directly-on-top-of-all-window)